# How to get drive letter of mapped network drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, cmd

I need to create a script or batch file to run on multiple computers that unmaps a network share `\\serverName\shareName` and maps a new network share `\\newServer\newShareName`

I can unmap the network drives by using:

```
net use /delete X:
```

and map the new share with:

```
net use * \\newServer\newShareName
```

but the problem is the drive letter is going to be different on every computer.

How would I check what letter `\\serverName\shareName` is mapped to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2,3" %%i in ('net use') do if '%%j=='\\servername\sharename set drive=%%i
```

this should work `;)`

Comment: I am getting %%i was unexpected at this time

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.