# Determine what drive letter a network share is mapped to using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Issue:
I am having trouble identifying the drive letter that a network share is mapped to using a batch file.

Background:
We map and use about a dozen network shared drives at work, and the batch file currently maps the drive to the "usual" drive letter. But I want to know if it is mapped to any letter (and if so, what that letter is) because we have over 200 PCs that use these mapped drives, and the letter is often different, so mapping it again to the "usual" letter results in duplicated mapped network drives.

I can see that the network share is mapped to a drive in `net use`, and it is accessible using both UNC path or the mapped drive letter, so not sure why I can't get the drive letter.

I located the following 3 answers for this issue, but for some reason, none of them are working for me. The URLs, code, and results obtained from each are below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

[Mapping a network drive without hardcoding a drive letter in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716422/mapping-a-network-drive-without-hardcoding-a-drive-letter-in-a-batch-file)

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('net use ^| find "\\NetworkShare1\Share1"') do set netdrive=%%i
```

Result: \NetworkShare1\Share1 has been mapped

---

[Return users mapped drive letter from network drive remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453658/return-users-mapped-drive-letter-from-network-drive-remote)

```
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%D IN ('net use ^| find ":" ^| find /I "\\NetworkShare1\Share1"') DO ECHO Drive letter is %%D
```

Result: Drive letter is \NetworkShare1\Share1

---

[How to get drive letter of mapped network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555441/how-to-get-drive-letter-of-mapped-network-drive)

```
for /f "tokens=2,3" %%i in ('net use') do if '%%j=='\\NetworkShare1\Share1 set drive=%%i
echo %drive%
```

Result: Echo is off.

Comment: What is the result of you using `net use` alone in command prompt?

Comment: @NekoMusume Using `net use` alone shows a list of all the mapped network drives as expected.

Comment: What about this: `wmic LogicalDisk where "ProviderName='\\\\NetworkShare\\Share1'" get DeviceID /VALUE` (each `\ `needs to be escaped for the `wmic` command line by doubling); this should return the mapped drive letter if there is such...

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl. You might want to add your explanation for ‘/‘ in your comment above to your answer below. It is good clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my windows 10 machine:

```
@echo off
set UNC=\\yourserver\yourshare
set drv=

for /f "delims=: " %%a in ('net use ^| find /i "%UNC%"') do set drv=%%a
if defined drv (
   echo "%UNC%" is mapped to %drv%:
   ) else (
      echo "%UNC%" is not mapped to anything.
)
echo/
pause
```

Note there is a space after the `:`

Also I should note that if the share is mapped to multiple drive letters this will only return the "last" drive letter mapped.  I believe it is alphabetical.

You know what -- I'm going to suggest a change.  This one will list all drives mapped to the path, **and** it will include partial matches.  In other words, if you search for \serv1\data it will also match \serv1\data\subfolder.  But then it will also match \serv1\datagram.  This might be useful or a problem.

```
@echo off
set "UNC=\\yourserver\yourshare"
set UNCfound=no

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ('net use ^| find /i "%UNC%"') do (
   echo "%%~b" is mapped to %%a:
   set UNCfound=yes
)
if "%UNCfound%"=="no" echo "%UNC%" is not mapped to anything.

echo/
pause
```

From my testing, if you add a space in the `find` expression, you can do an exact match:

```
@echo off
set "UNC=\\yourserver\yourshare"
set UNCfound=no

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ('net use ^| find /i "%UNC% "') do (
   echo "%%~b" is mapped to %%a:
   set UNCfound=yes
)
if "%UNCfound%"=="no" echo "%UNC%" is not mapped to anything.

echo/
pause
```

Comment: This works in Windows 7 Enterprise as well. Just what I needed, thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Note that [`net use`](https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html) may return network shares that are connected but not mapped to a drive letter.

Comment: @avery_larry thanks for the update for multiple mappings. It could prove useful.

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks for the reminder on mapped locations not mapped to a drive letter showing in ‘net use’. Thankfully should not be an issue in our enterprise environment, but still, something to keep in mind!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach featuring the [`wmic` command](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html), using the [`Win32_LogicalDisk` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk):

```cmd
@echo off
set "UNC=\\ATMEDFS01\workgroups\R&D\Systems"
set "DRV="

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('
    wmic LogicalDisk where "DriveType=4 and ProviderName='%UNC:\=\\%'" get DeviceID /VALUE 2^> nul
') do for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%J in ("%%I") do set "DRV=%%K"

if defined DRV (
    echo The network share "%UNC%" is mapped to drive %DRV%.
) else (
    echo The network share "%UNC%" is NOT mapped to a drive.
)
```

In the `where` clause of the `wmic` command line, every `\` needs to be escaped by doubling it; that is what the [sub-string substitution expression](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) `%UNC:\=\\%` is for.

Comment: You're welcome! Please don't post "thanks" comments, rather read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)